# How to iterate through each value in a column with conditions and create a new column with new values

Tags: python

I have a cumulative sum % column in my data frame.
I would like to have a function that iterate through each cell of that column and returns a value in the newly created column M_quintile.

```
cumsum  cumsumperc  M_quintile
   465     0.001320   a number between 1-5    
   439     0.002499   a number between 1-5        
   213     0.003624   a number between 1-5        
   616     0.004583   a number between 1-5        
   527     0.005468   a number between 1-5
```

Here's the function I currently have:

```
def score(x):
    if x <= 0.20:
        return 5
    elif x <= 0.40:
        return 4
    elif x <= 0.60:
        return 3
    elif x <= 0.80:
        return 2
    else:
        return 1
```

How do i apply this function on a specific column specifically to the cumsumperc column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`pd.cut()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.cut.html). In your case:

```
df['M_quintile'] = pd.cut(df.cumsumperc, bins=[-np.inf,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,np.inf], labels=[5,4,3,2,1])

>>> df
   cumsum  cumsumperc M_quintile
0     465    0.001320          5
1     439    0.002499          5
2     213    0.003624          5
3     616    0.004583          5
4     527    0.005468          5
```

This says: if `cumsumperc` is between negative infinity and 0.2 (the first 2 values in the `bins` argument), assign it 5 (the first value in your `labels` argument), if it's between 0.2 and 0.4, assign it 4, and so on until if it's between 0.8 and infinity, assign it 1.

In your case, all values are between negative infinity and 0.2, so they all get assigned 5. Just for illustration, look what happens if you add another value:

```
>>> df
   cumsum  cumsumperc
0     465    0.001320
1     439    0.002499
2     213    0.003624
3     616    0.004583
4     527    0.005468
5     999    0.720000
>>> df['M_quintile'] = pd.cut(df.cumsumperc, bins=[-np.inf,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,np.inf], labels=[5,4,3,2,1])
>>> df
   cumsum  cumsumperc M_quintile
0     465    0.001320          5
1     439    0.002499          5
2     213    0.003624          5
3     616    0.004583          5
4     527    0.005468          5
5     999    0.720000          2
```

Comment: what is -np? is it part of the numpy package?

Comment: Yeah, it's negative infinity. You can also access it without explicitly importing numpy by using `-pd.np.inf`, or if you're just looking say between 0 and 1, replace `-np.inf` with 0 and `np.inf` with 1

Answer (score 1):

I think there are better ways to do this through Pandas, but if you wanted to use your own function, you can use the apply function.

```
import pandas as pd

def score(x):
    if x <= 0.20:
        return 5
    elif x <= 0.40:
        return 4
    elif x <= 0.60:
        return 3
    elif x <= 0.80:
        return 2
    else:
        return 1 

df['M_quintile'] = df['cumsumperc'].apply(score)
```

Output:

```
   cumsum  cumsumperc  M_quintile
0     465    0.001320           5
1     439    0.002499           5
2     213    0.003624           5
3     616    0.004583           5
4     527    0.005468           5
```